# Issue with locally saving data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"savedKeyWords": "a"});   
chrome.storage.local.get(["savedKeyWords"],function(data){
    alert(data[1])
});
```

the alert sends undefined, this is called in a startup function.
I cant seem to figure out how to save data locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"savedKeyWords": "a"});   
chrome.storage.local.get(["savedKeyWords"],function(data){
    alert(data.savedKeyWords);
});
```

Chrome.storage.local.get() returns an object with items in their key-value mappings, so you have to use the index of the key in your search pattern.